# UILabel bad looking like bitmap

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a problem with UILabel in my project. 
`UITableViewCell` label text look like good.
but others labels something wired...

I used code like this

```js
let myFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .regular)
myLabel.font = myFont
```

[image]

why bad look like bitmap?

Comment: Is the screenshot from a device/simulator or it's from your storyboard?

Comment: How do you make your layout? Do you add the labels from code? Do you use constraints with multiplier != 1? Show us how you put that labels on the screen.

Comment: Please share some code. If added through XIB, share a screenshot of constraints used